# Autoloading files in subfolders to helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, directory-structure

I want to organize some helpers in subfolders in the helpers directory.  I figured adding this in the initializer would do the trick, but not luck:

```
  config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/helpers/*"].find_all { |f| File.stat(f).directory? }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add this to your `application.rb` file.